# CMYK ConTeXt colors in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, context

Colors defined via the internal `\definecolor` macro in ConTeXt cannot be used in TikZ when the CMYK system is used.

Is there a way to convert them or tick a setting so that TikZ can use them?

### Minimal example:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\definecolor[c][c=1]
\starttext
\tikz\node[c]{t};
\stoptext
```

**Expected:** cyan “t”
**Received:** black “t” and `Package pgf: Error! Color c has an unsupported color model..`

---

**Edit:** TikZ does use ConTeXt colors defined with the RGB color model:

```
\definecolor[r][r=1]
\tikz\node[r]{t};
```

This gives me a red “t” as expected. So I don’t want to know how to define colors explicitly for use in TikZ, but what code I have to add somewhere add to make the two lines`\definecolor[c][c=1]` and `\tikz\node[c]{t};` from the minimal example work together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that `pgf` does not have any built-in support for `cmyk` when using ConTeXt. As a result, the macro `\pgfutil@registercolor`, which chooses colour models, is hard-coded not to try anything other than `rgb` and `gray`. Thus we need alter that macro and provide the necessary internal conversion:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\definecolor[c][c=1]
\starttext
\unprotect
\def\pgfutil@registercolor#1{%
  \edef\pgf@temp{\PDFcolor{#1}}%
  \edef\pgf@marshal{\noexpand\pgfutil@in@{g}{\pgf@temp}}%
  \pgf@marshal
  \ifpgfutil@in@
    \expandafter\pgfutil@context@parse@gray\pgf@temp\pgf@stop{#1}%
  \else
    \edef\pgf@marshal{\noexpand\pgfutil@in@{rg}{\pgf@temp}}%
    \pgf@marshal
    \ifpgfutil@in@
      \expandafter\pgfutil@context@parse@rgb\pgf@temp\pgf@stop{#1}%
    \else
      \edef\pgf@marshal{\noexpand\pgfutil@in@{k}{\pgf@temp}}%
      \pgf@marshal
      \ifpgfutil@in@
        \expandafter\pgfutil@context@parse@cmyk\pgf@temp\pgf@stop{#1}%
      \else 
        \PackageError{pgf}{Color #1 has an unsupported color model.}{}%
        \pgfutil@definecolor{#1}{gray}{0}%
      \fi
    \fi
  \fi
}
\def\pgfutil@context@parse@cmyk#1 #2 #3 #4k#5\pgf@stop #6{%
  \pgfutil@definecolor{#6}{cmyk}{#1,#2,#3,#4}%
}
\def\pgfutil@emu@cmyk#1#2,#3,#4,#5\@nil{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname
    {\xcolor@{}{}{cmyk}{#2,#3,#4,#5}}%
}

\protect
\tikz\node[c]{t};
\stoptext
```

---

**Original answer (to a slightly different question!)**

Two things are going on here. First, `pgf` does not support ConTeXt's `\definecolor`: there is a note to the effect in the manual. So you need to use `\pgfutil@definecolor` instead. Secondly, there is no built-in code for a `cmyk` model when working with ConTeXt. However, this does not seem to be too hard to emulate:

```
\usemodule[tikz]
\unprotect
\def\pgfutil@emu@cmyk#1#2,#3,#4,#5\@nil{%
  \expandafter\def\csname\string\color@#1\endcsname
    {\xcolor@{}{}{cmyk}{#2,#3,#4,#5}}%
}
\pgfutil@definecolor{c}{cmyk}{1,0,0,0}
\protect
\starttext
\tikz\node[c]{t};
\stoptext
```

Comment: It’s a nice answer on how to define CMYK-colors for TikZ from inside a ConTeXt document. But my question was what code i should add at one position to enable TikZ to use ConTeXt’s colors.

Comment: @flying sheep: That may be rather more tricky - while `pgf` is usable in plain and ConTeXt, it's pretty clear that the colour support is tied quite closely to LaTeX's approach.

Comment: See my edited answer on what works already and thus tells me that there must be a way to create hybrid ConTeXt/TikZ colors. I don’t need them to be CMYK internally, just defined via CMYK. Also: Isn’t `\unprotect \dosomethingwith@inside \protect` the canonical way?

Comment: @flying sheep: Answer updated to reflect altered question. On `\unprotect`, as I'm not a ConTeXt regular I was not sure if that was for `@` or only for `!`, _etc._: I've altered the code.

Comment: Wow, that’s the answer I was looking for. Tear this stubborn module’s heart out, [overcharge it](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=36lSzUMBJnc) and stuff it back in! Any chance to get this into the core? Also, I need the ability to upvote more than once. PS: I just clarified the question, I did not alter it. I meant to ask this from the start, just firgured I’d have to add more specificity.

Comment: sadly, it does not work: http://pastebin.com/vXmj8mpi

Comment: @flying sheep: I have `ConTeXt  ver: 2011.05.18 18:04 MKII  fmt: 2011.9.7  int: english/english` and `pgf` 2.10, and all seems to be well.

Comment: i have `MKIV 2011.08.27 13:24` and TikZ/PGF 2.10

Comment: @flying sheep: I've updated the answer again, and it should now work with both MkII and MkIV.

Comment: thank you very much. i’m curious: is there a reason to use mkii?

Comment: and may i contribute your code on the TikZ and/or ConTeXt mailing lists? like “Joseph Wright has written a TikZ addition that allows TikZ to use ConTeXt CMYK colors: …”?

Comment: In the past, I have had no response from the pgf/tikz maintainers for patches to provide better ConTeXt support. One example is ConTeXt support for `circuittikz` package, which fails with ConTeXt. The fix is to add one space to one of the internal tikz macros (see circuittikz documentation for details). It has not been accepted for almost two years :-( I have stopped spending effort in trying to debug tikz code.

Comment: TikZ is awesome, but this makes me kind of angry. Why wouldn’t someone accept patches?

Comment: @Joseph: your patch has been applied to the cvs: http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&atid=752792&aid=3407097&group_id=142562 (see comment)